# Python: FM Demod Implementation

Tags: python, signal-processing, modulation

I am thinking of analyzing a time-series of some particular values as it were a frequency-modulated signal.

I was looking for a Python implementation of an FM demodulator.
I know there is a demodulator function in Matlab and Octave; for Python I found this [FreqDemod](https://freqdemod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package, but it doesn't seem to do what I want to do.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?  It looks like it does basic FM demodulation?

Comment: I want to do FM demodulation indeed. This package I found takes the signal to demodulate not as an array but in its own special class. I don't want to bother with learning all that, i need to stay focused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a Python function that does FM demodulation on complex samples.

```
import numpy as np

def fm_demod(x, df=1.0, fc=0.0):
    ''' Perform FM demodulation of complex carrier.

    Args:
        x (array):  FM modulated complex carrier.
        df (float): Normalized frequency deviation [Hz/V].
        fc (float): Normalized carrier frequency.

    Returns:
        Array of real modulating signal.
    '''

    # Remove carrier.
    n = np.arange(len(x))
    rx = x*np.exp(-1j*2*np.pi*fc*n)

    # Extract phase of carrier.
    phi = np.arctan2(np.imag(rx), np.real(rx))

    # Calculate frequency from phase.
    y = np.diff(np.unwrap(phi)/(2*np.pi*df))

    return y
```

Comment: Just as a note to future readers, this function outputs to a single track of audio and is not stereo. It's definitely useful for checking if you are recording your SDR's data to a wav file correctly though.

Comment: What does sp means in code example ?

Comment: It is scipy package.  There is an implicit import of scipy at top of file.  Should probably be using numpy instead of scipy now.  I have updated answer with import.

Answer (score 1):

FM demodulation can be achieved next procedure.
It is very naive but simple.

Where the message signal `m(t)` and carrirer frequency `f_c`, the modulated signal has next form.

`y(t) = Ac sin(fc *t + fd *int_0^t m(tau) dtau)`

1. Derivation: `y'(t) = Ac (f_c + m(t)) y(t)`
2. Enveloping: `y_eve(t) = Ac (f_c +m(t))`
3. DC-blocking and scaling: `m(t)`

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import hilbert

def fm_demodulate(sig_fm, time):
    y_d = np.gradient(sig_fm, time)
    y_envelop = np.abs(hilbert(y_d))
    reutrn y_envelop
```

The above code used `hilbert` filter for enveloping, you can use the other filters.